# IE 8 "Access is denied"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, shopify

I am receiving an "Access is Denied" error in internet explorer as shown in the screenshot below:

The strange part is that if I refresh it a few times, occasionally the page will load without errors and the script runs fine which lead me to believe that the option_selections script would load before the core013, but I tried moving the script and got the same results.

[image: Internet Explorer Access is Denied Error]
 [image]

I am working on a website in Shopify and do not have access to core013.js in the first error. I do however have control over the option_selection.js. ( I can execute it before or after core013.js code. I have placed the option_selection.js code above and below the core013 script  with the same results.

The site in question is located [here](http://highbrowvapor.com/collections/frontpage/products/apricot-1).

Comment: Everything woks fine for IE 9.

Comment: If it works sometimes but not others, it must be some sort of timing issue. Since JavaScript is asynchronous in nature, maybe sometimes resources (JS files? Ajax-fetched content/scripts?) are being returned in an unexpected order. I don't know the specific problem or even if I'm right, but that's my guess.

Comment: In IE 9 running browsermode IE 8 it says some elements are blocked by the native IE filter settings (against spam, viruses ...)!

Comment: @powtac that is good news; unfortunately the client is paying me to specifically fix this IE8 isssue :/

Comment: And Chrome that you're doing cross-site in your frames

Comment: Ok, I fixed the issue. Basically I not only needed to move the option_selection.js up to the top but I also needed to move the code that called it to the top as well. Arg... embarrassingly simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue. Basically I not only needed to move the option_selection.js up to the top but I also needed to move the code that called it to the top as well. Arg... embarrassingly simple...

Comment: No worries! Make sure to hit the giant checkmark to mark your question as answered. Note that you get a sweet achievement for answering your own question the first time you do it :)